# timestamp field in presto parquet table showing bad data

Tags: hive, parquet, presto

I have  an external table created in hive 0.131 using parquet

```
CREATE external table if not exists tbl (
          occurred_at timestamp,
          user_phone string,
          usergk BIGINT,
          enabled boolean,
          classgk int,
          title string,
          eta int,
          latitude decimal(9,6),
          longitude decimal(9,6),
          device_type string,
          device_os_version string,
          event_at_utc timestamp

         )

    PARTITIONED BY (country string, occured_date date)
    STORED AS parquet
    LOCATION 's3://XXX'
```

when I query in HIVE 0.13 everything looks fine but when I tried to do a simple query on this table in Presto (i.e select * from tbl limit 10 ) I got an error:

```
Can not read Parquet column: [HiveColumnHandle{clientId=hive,
name=occured_date, hiveType=date, hiveColumnIndex=-1, partitionKey=true}]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not read Parquet column: [HiveColumnHandle{clientId=hive, name=occured_date, hiveType=date, hiveColumnIndex=-1, partitionKey=true}]
```

when I wrote down specific column (i.e select occurred_at from tbl limit 10) I got odd results like '14173-10-07 02:42:56' while in hive it shows meaningful results

can it be related to the parquet format hive 0.13 is using?

Comment: did you ever resolve it?